# What happened to the original English dubs of Lupin III by Streamline Pictures?

Tags: lupin-the-third

Does anyone know where I can get the old Lupin DVD's containing the original English dubs by Streamline Pictures? The ones you can buy on amazon.com seem to be done with new English audio recording with different voice actors.

Comment: ...or perhaps downloads for just the audio. I've already bought the new dvd's. thinking i could splice it in myself

Comment: https://nitrateglow.wordpress.com/2015/03/16/the-things-that-wouldnt-shut-up-streamline-manga-entertainment-and-the-castle-of-cagliostro/ Apparently the newest DVD release contains the Streamline dub.